# Converting double to long long in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, double

My code is very simple:

```
long long GetAmountFromString(NSString* string){
    NSLog(@"double value %f", [string doubleValue]);
    NSLog(@"double value * 100 %f", [string doubleValue]*100);
    NSLog(@"long long %lld", (long long)([string doubleValue]*100));
    return (long long)([string doubleValue]*100);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        GetAmountFromString(@"4324.69");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, it's output is strange:

```
double value 4324.690000
double value * 100 432469.000000
long long 432468
```

What I expect is 342469. Who can tell me the right way to do this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally decimal values cannot be precisely represented by floating-point types. So, the double value * 100 is actually less than 432469. Round it to get the result you expect.

```
double round(double number)
{
    return number < 0.0 ? ceil(number - 0.5) : floor(number + 0.5);
}

NSLog(@"long long %lld", (long long)(round([string doubleValue]*100)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSDecimalNumber.

```
NSString* string = @"4324.69";
NSDecimalNumber* value = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: string];
value = [value decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy: [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1
                                                                        exponent:2
                                                                      isNegative:NO]];
NSLog(@"value %@", [value descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);
```

edit:
The whole purpose of NSDecimalNumber is to provide a mechanism which is not subject to decimal numbers not representable as doubles or floats. It tends to obviate the kinds of tricks your code seems to be aiming for.